# Make download speed limit for free file

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, plugins, directadmin

I have a file in wp
Is paid file
I need to share it but not with best download speed with limited

If pay, can download via unlimited speed

The paid and free link is same and is on same file
Example:
Dl1.globalsystemformobile.com/zip.1

Is a good way to do this?